# Sound Blaster Audigy FX stopped working in 22.10

Tags: sound, alsa, 22.10, pipewire, sound-blaster

Since upgrading to Kinetic (22.10), and the change in the sound from pulseaudio to pipewire, my sound has stopped working. alsamixer shows it, as does lspci, it just seems that pipewire is blind. I fiddled once and had it show up briefly in my sound options, and then it disappeared again. Does anyone know how to correct this?

lspci shows:

```
04:00.0 Audio device: Creative Labs Sound Core3D [Sound Blaster Recon3D / Z-Series] (rev 01)
```

aplay shows:

```
card 1: Creative [HDA Creative], device 0: ALC898 Analog [ALC898 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Comment: Interestingly, the following works:

`systemctl --user start pipewire-pulse.service`
wait ~30 sec
`systemctl --user restart pulseaudio.service`

But I am not sure why it does, and I believe this is what I fiddled with before to make it work temporarily.

Comment: That technique does not stick after a reboot. I have to redo it every reboot.

Comment: Does anyone have a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

So the solution I came up with (found), but is not great because I have to do it every time I restart my computer is:

```
systemctl --user restart pipewire-pulse.service
systemctl --user restart pulseaudio.service
```

I hope a better, more sustainable solution shows up eventually. Like maybe it gets fixed more directly.

Comment: Haven't looked into it but try combining tools - cron might be useful if you have to do it every reboot. https://phoenixnap.com/kb/crontab-reboot

Comment: I considered that, just haven't yet.